# What is the good way to print out string with integer in haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
import Text.Printf
printf "the length of this list is %d"  length' [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I do this, but it failed.

```
'func.hs:38:58:
    No instance for (Num t0) arising from the literal `1'
    The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus three others
    In the expression: 1
    In the third argument of `printf', namely `[1, 2, 3, 4, ....]'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      printf "the length of this list is %d" length' [1, 2, 3, 4, ....]"
```

Comment: I'm guessing you meant to enclose ``length' [1,2,3,4,5]`` in parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to fix is that you're applying `printf'` to 3 arguments, not 2 like you think. You want to explicitly surround the application of `length'` in parens.

```
printf "string" (length' [1, 2, 3, 4])
printf "string" $ length' [1, 2, 3, 4] -- The more idiomatic version of the above.
```

If `length'` has a sane type (similar to `length` or `genericLength` than this will eliminate your type error.

Answer (score 0):

either `putStrLn` or `putStr`.  Just use `show` if the type is of the `Show` typeclass which most types you will deal with are, or you can write your own instance.

```
putStr $ show $ length [1..5]
```

Comment: @jozefg Whoops, that comment was before my coffee! My point still stands, though – if you're gonna use `putStrLn` you can just as well use `print`.